# Actualizar apps pelo Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, app

Fiz uma *app* no Android Studio,acabei por a publicar no Google Play. agora queria saber como posso fazer uma actualização da mesma? Quais os passos necessários? Se basta alterar *app* no android studio e compilar como debbug ? ou se tem outra maneira

Comment: Tem como você explicar melhor um pouco?

Comment: Recompila e reinstala. 1/2 pergunta, 1/2 resposta.

Comment: Ah? Tem de elaborar melhor a pergunta. Ninguém percebeu o que você quer.

Comment: Explique melhor pra eu poder lhe orientar amigo, você quer atualizar seu aplicativo no Google Play e não ta sabendo como faz?

Comment: Ele fez um app, e quer saber como faz pra agora lançar atualizações para esse app, exemplo ele lança a versão 1.0, ele quer saber como faz pra lançar a versão 1.1 e ja publicar em cima da versão antiga na Google Play.

Comment: @RobertoAlbino você está deduzindo isso?

Comment: Eu consegui interpretar perfeitamente a pergunta dele.

Comment: @RobertoAlbino você entendeu porque leu a perguntada editada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vai no arquivo build.gradle (Module:app) e muda as seguintes linhas:

Se seu app tiver:

```
defaultConfig {

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Muda para:

```
defaultConfig {

            versionCode 2
            versionName "1.1"
        }
```

Depois gera sua apk e envia para o Google Play.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Mauro ja me ajudou